# Angular Directive - ngRepeat Adding Removing from Array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to iterate over an object property which is an array of objects, in order to render input fields. I need to be able to dynamically add/remove objects from the array and display the corresponding elements. I'm able to add/remove objects from the array but the view is not updated. I've tried using $timeout but it's not updating the view. How can I render the correct elements based on which objects were added/removed from the array.

***main template***

```
<tbody carrier></tbody>
```

***carrier.directive.js***

```
angular.module('carrierModule')
.directive('carrier', carrier);
carrier.$inject = [
  '$translate',
  '$httpParamSerializer',
  '$timeout'
];
function carrier($translate, $httpParamSerializer, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {

    },
    templateUrl: 'app/carrier/carrier.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.timeRangeOptions = [
        {name: "All days of the week", value: 1},
        {name: "Discounted time per day", value: 2},
        {name: "Any time", value: 3}
      ];
      scope.carriers = {
        "Verizon": {times: [{start: "10:00", end: "12:00"}], selectedDiscountedTimeRange: scope.timeRangeOptions[0]},
        "T-Mobile": {times: [{start: "10:00", end: "12:00"}], selectedDiscountedTimeRange: scope.timeRangeOptions[0]},
        "Spring": {times: [{start: "10:00", end: "12:00"}], selectedDiscountedTimeRange: scope.timeRangeOptions[0]},
        "Orange": {times: [{start: "10:00", end: "12:00"}], selectedDiscountedTimeRange: scope.timeRangeOptions[0]}
      };
      scope.carrierOrder = ["Orange", "Spring", "T-Mobile", "Verizon"];
      scope.selectedDiscountedTimeRange = scope.timeRangeOptions[0];
      scope.addTimeFields = function(carrier) {
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.carriers[carrier].times.push({start: "10:00", end: "12:00"});
        });
      };

    }
    // link
  }
}
```

***carrier.tpl.html***

```
<tr ng-repeat="(carrier, value) in carriers track by $index">
  <td>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <carrier-time carriers="carriers" carrier-name="carrier" ng-repeat="time in carriers[carrier] track by $index"></carrier-time>
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o add-time-btn" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="addTimeFields(carrier)"></i>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

***carrier-time.directive.js***

```
angular.module('carrierModule')
.directive('carrierTime', carrierTime);
carrierTime.$inject = [
  '$translate',
  '$httpParamSerializer',
  '$timeout'
];
function carrierTime($translate, $httpParamSerializer, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      carriers: '=',
      carrierName: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/carrier/carrier-time.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.removeTimeFields = function(carrier) {
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.carriers[carrier].times.pop();
        });

      };
    }
    // link
  }
}

***carrier-time.tpl.html***

  <div class="form-group" ng-mouseenter="showRemoveTimeFields = !showRemoveTimeFields">
    <input class="form-control start" type="time"><span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span><input class="form-control end" type="time">
  </div>
  <i ng-if="showRemoveTimeFields" class="fa fa-times-circle remove-time" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="removeTimeFields(carrierName)"></i>
```

Comment: Try $evalAsync instead of $timeout.

Comment: Thats because directive doesnt run compile block once excecuted. you have to use $watch for doing that.

Comment: Or do a location.reload() so it refreshes the list on reload.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't looping over the correct property. My ng-repeat was missing the 'times' property i.e., ng-repeat="time in carriers[carrier].times